# Can we set default value for limit in loopback framework find API?

Tags: loopbackjs

I have a API `http://localhost:3000/todos?filter[where][type]=read&filter[limit]=2`

Want to specify default limit as 20 and also want to validate limit value to be less than or equal to 20.

Wanted to check if we can have validation and also default value for limit filter?

Answer (score 0):

You may handle it in your endpoint,

```js
const filterData: Filter<Todos> = {...filter};
filterData['limit'] = filterData['limit'] && filterData['limit'] > 20 ? 20 : filterData['limit']
return this.todosRepository.find(filterData);
```